# Why recent apps are showing on pressing the back button in android?

Tags: android, android-launcher

I am making a `launcher` in `Android`. When I am at home in my `launcher` and pressing `back button` of device, it showing `recent apps`.

For `recent apps`, there is an another button on device. I don't want to show recent apps on pressing of back button.

I haven't overriden the `onBackPressed()` method yet.

How to solve this and why it's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because that's what Android does when it doesn't know have anything on the stack.  When you pressed back, you finished your home Activity which left it with nowhere to go.  Since this is a launcher, you should override onBackPressed to do nothing.  That will fix it.

Comment: No, home Activity is there, it doesn't go and now i tried by override onBackPressed() method but not working.. :(

Comment: Post your code for onBackPressed.  Make sure it doesn't call super or finish.

Comment: Hey, thanks.. problem fixed.. actually I was calling super in onBackPressed() .. :-)